# How to wire an outlet

Tags: electrical

I need to replace a regular 3 prong outlet to one of these for a tool. I have tried multiple arrangements but none turn the tool on. The tool needs 15 amps, I have a 20 amp outlet and 15 amp fuse. Yes I know the fuse will need replacing but in the fuse is not being overloaded/break[image][image]

Comment: What size is the wire to the receptacle, and how long will the tool be left running for?  Also, what *is* the tool in question, and are we talking about a branch circuit shared with other receptacles or a dedicated branch circuit solely for said tool?

Comment: This tool is an air compressor.  The wire is a 14 Guage. Running for an hour on and off [about]. It is a branch curcuit but nothing is running off of those branch outlets.

Comment: What's the nameplate rating on the air compressor?

Comment: This receptacle is a NEMA 6-20, which needs a 240VAC 20A circuit, you can't just swap out a 120VAC receptacle with one of these and expect it to work, and you may damage your 240VAC equipment by trying to run it at 120VAC. I believe your 14 gauge wire is not sufficient to run a 20A circuit, you'd need at least 12 gauge. Also, note that these wires are wrapped around the screw terminals the wrong way, they should be wrapped clockwise.

Comment: Get back to TreePhaseEel with the motor nameplate data, he knows of an exception which may make this permissible.

Comment: Makes sense why the light turned on when I turned the on switch to the compressor and vice versa. The compressor was pulling all the electricity from down the branch then

Comment: Also, I believe your side-wiring is backward. Maybe it's not a problem, but I've always heard to have the wire wrap in the *same* direction as the screw turns when you tighten it.

Comment: The receptacle was made to where it has to go backward or it will hit the plastics

Comment: I actually don't understand what you mean. I've never seen that before.

Comment: Is this air compressor fastened in place, or portable?

Comment: It is not portable. About 3 foot long

Comment: It has two wheels only. Semi portable.

Comment: In this context "*fastened in place*" means that it's attached to the structure of the building in some way, where it would require you to remove fasteners to move the device. "*Portable*" means that it is not attached to the structure, and can be moved simply by lifting/pulling/pushing/etc. it.  So in your case, it's portable.

Comment: As Johnny has pointed out, that is a 240 volt device. You cannot power it with a 120 volt circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compressor is not working, because you're connecting it to a 120 volt circuit. According to the nameplate on the equipment, you should be connecting it to a 240 volt 20 ampere circuit.

Comment: Update to everyone. I put the curcuit on a 20 amp breaker and the compressor  did not turn.

Comment: @DIYguy 20 amp at 240 volts, or 120 volts?

Comment: Two pole breaker needed. I understand now. Then run 10-2 wire right? Connect two hot wires or one hot one neutral and one ground